# How to lock element of array using TBB/OpenMP

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, openmp, tbb

I have a very big array read/write by several threads. Each thread will only rw one element of them at a time, so it would be a bad idea to lock the whole array. What I am expecting is something like

```
// before threads
lock_t Lock[NUM_THREADS]; 

...

// during threads
get_lock(Lock[thread_id], element_id);
array[element_id]+=10; // some operations
release_lock(Lock[thread_id]);
```

So my question is, what is the best strategy of designing `get_lock` and `release_lock`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using OpenMP you can obtain an equivalent behavior using the `atomic` construct:

```
// during threads
#pragma omp atomic
array[element_id]+=10; // some operations
```

Just to give you an idea of its semantic, here is an excerpt from the OpenMP 3.1 standard:

> The **atomic** construct ensures that a specific storage location is
>   accessed atomically, rather than exposing it to the possibility of
>   multiple, simultaneous reading and writing threads that may result in
>   indeterminate values

On the other hand, if you decide to use Intel TBB, you can take a look at the [atomic template class](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/tbb_sa/help/index.htm#reference/reference.htm).